# Text style for marginpar

Tags: formatting, marginpar

Is there a way to change the font, font size and so on for `\marginpar` with a standard LaTeX macro, i.e. without something such as `\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar` (cp. [Problem with Customized Marginpar (in Combination With a ToMarginpar)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46654/8631). The `\marginnote` package e.g. provides `\marginfont`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
Text text text\marginpar{A short note.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To print out a margin the contents will be save in a savebox. So you can manipulate the default implementation of `latex.ltx` which is as follows:

```
\long\def\@ympar#1{%
  \@savemarbox\@marbox{#1}%
  \global\setbox\@currbox\copy\@marbox
  \@xympar}
```

The mandatory argument is the contents. So simple use:

```
\long\def\@ympar#1{%
  \@savemarbox\@marbox{\tiny #1}%
  \global\setbox\@currbox\copy\@marbox
  \@xympar}
```

Based on the special symbol `@` you have to use `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is with `\RenewDocumentCommand`:

```
\NewCommandCopy{\oldmarginpar}{\marginpar}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\marginpar}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\oldmarginpar{\mymparsetup #2}}
    {\oldmarginpar[\mymparsetup #1]{\mymparsetup #2}}}

\newcommand{\mymparsetup}{\itshape}
```

In the `\mymparsetup` command you can put all customizations you want. In this way we can keep the behavior with the optional argument to `\marginpar`.

Note: see edit history for the older version with `\let`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I don't see why: if one does the *right* redefinition, there's no problem. `:)`

Comment: I thought that using `\let` has the side effect of losing the ability to have optional arguments. But your `\oldmarginpar` can still parse the leading []?

Comment: @Andy: You can use the let operation for commands with optional argument. However a more robust way is to use `\LetLtxMacro` provided by the package `letltxmacro`.

Comment: @Andy Actually `\marginpar` has *no* argument. I'll add something to my answer.